# ASP.NET MVC read write set property

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

This question might have been asked and if so, feel free to point me in the right direction.

I have a View Model with a property that looks like this:

```
private decimal _paymentAmountPaid;
public decimal PaymentAmountPaid
{
    get { return CalPaymentAmountPaid(); }
    set
    {
        _paymentAmountPaid = value;
    }
}
```

When the view loads it displays the correct amount that i want it to in a control (a kendo numeric textbox).    But if the user changes the value in the textbox, say from 100 to 150,  it will still post the value of 100.  How do i get it to post the value of what ever the user changes it to?

Comment: How does your form (inside your view) look like?

Comment: It would seem a bit unintuitive for any consuming code to set a value and then get something different when immediately reading back that value.  Perhaps the calculated version should be its own property?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your getter you don't return the value set by the user but calculate the value again:

```
get { return CalPaymentAmountPaid(); } // always calculates the value
```

If the user set the value, you probably should return the local value later:

```
private decimal _paymentAmountPaid;
private bool _userSetValue;
public decimal PaymentAmountPaid
{
    get { return _userSetValue ? _paymentAmountPaid : CalPaymentAmountPaid(); }
    set
    {
        _userSetValue = true;
        _paymentAmountPaid = value;
    }
}
```